# implementing users notification on the same table or on a seperated relationed table (laravel)

Tags: mysql, database

i have a user and invoice table which i want to make notifications for them that they will be able to turn them on/off .
now my question is that should i add 5 columns for example on users table and 3 on invoice table to make it on or off or make 2 tables as below :
`notification_list` and : `notification_user` to make user to be able to turn the notification from user model and invoice on or off .
the problem here is that `notification_user` will be a massive table as soon as the users table growth . for every user i need to add 5 records at least .
i am using laravel and the tables and relations of it .so i can use morph relations but i still dont know which one is better to implement it inside the table or on a seperated table . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If this can be toggled globally for all invoices all at once

You definitely need `notification_list`, but instead of `notification_user` I'd add extra column to `users` table or create something like `users_preferences` to store multiple user preferences. Creating separate table for each of preferences doesn't seem like a good solution

#### If this should be done for each invoice separately

You actually can't add extra columns to `invoices` and `users` table as you would be required to have one column for each user.

You have to use your solution Nr 2. But bare in mind that you don't need to create any records in table unless they differ from default behavior. That means you only add record to table when user toggles button. Also you can delete these records once invoice is no longer active. So this new table doesn't really grow as fast.

Comment: Reading again I started to think did I get your question correctly. Do you toggle ON / OFF globally for all invoice notifications or do you toggle it for each invoice separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use only one field for your user notification preferences. but this solution require good structuring.

It's base on the fact that what you need to track is just the state of the preference (on or off).

so save it as an integer containing the prefrence of the user. here is an example:

```
$preference1 = 1;
$preference2 = 0;
$preference3 = 0;
$preference4 = 1;
$preference5 = 0;

//the value to save is the integer result of the binary 01001
$preference = 1 * $preference1 + 2 * $preference2 + 4 * $preference3 + 8 * $preference4 + 16 * $preference5;
//or simply
$preference = bindec($pref5.$pref4.$pref3.$pref2.$pref1);
```

Now to check if a specific preference is enabled, use the bitwise comparison

```php
if ($preference & 4) { //preference 3 has value 4
    //preference 3 is on.
}

//you can also check multiple prefrences at the same time
if ($preference & 5 == 5) { //this is preference 3 and preference 1
    //user has both preference enabled
}
```

You can also use it in your database request

```php
$users = User::whereRaw("BIT_COUNT('prefrence' & 4)")->get();
//this will give you all the users having preference 3 enabled
```

To add more structure to this solution, you should declare constants in your user model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    const PREFRENCE1 = 1;
    const PREFRENCE2 = 2;
    const PREFRENCE3 = 4;
    const PREFRENCE4 = 8;
    const PREFRENCE5 = 16;
    //...
}

//This way everything will make more sense like:
$users = User::whereRaw("BIT_COUNT('prefrence' & ".User::PREFERENCE3.")")->get();

if ($preference & User::PREFERENCE3) {
    //preference 3 is on.
}
```

PS: Make sure that the integer size in the database in not under your number of preference to save.

Comment: I don't really see why would someone do this unless using system with super low resources. Multiple `bit` columns with correct naming like `receive_invoice_notifications` will make your code easier to read than this.

Comment: @NoOorZ24 this will make your solution expandable (and retractable) without having to change database structure. You can easily add new type of preference in your code alone.

Comment: i get where you are going with this, i would just try and abstract a lot of this away to not have to have someone deal with the bits